# Looking for the Javascript of these JQuery lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently learning HTML 5 + javascript, and one of the examples I'm looking at is written in JQuery. I realise that JQuery would be simpler to some people, but as I am just coming to terms with Javascript and no nothing of JQuery, I'm looking to get some lines of code translated from one to the other.

I know what these lines of code does, I'm just looking for it in JavaScript.

```
var showForm = function() {
if(editMode) {
    var transaction = transactions[editMode];
    amountField.value = transaction.amount;
    if(transaction.type) $('[value='+transaction.type+']').attr('checked',       'true');
    if(transaction.cleared) $('#cleared').attr('checked', 'true');
    noteField.value = transaction.note;
    dateField.value = transaction.date;
    $('#time').val(transaction.time);
    postcodeField.value = transaction.postcode;
    searchField.value = ''
} else {
     clearUI();
}

$('#formDiv').show();
$('#toolbar').hide();
$('#tableDiv').hide();
$('#map_div').hide();
$('#sum').hide();
```

Comment: FWIW, I learned jQuery first and am now filling-in the gaps in my javascript knowledge. It worked out well for me as I have now done several sites with some advanced scripting. [Here are some good jQ tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32) and also [phpAcademy](http://phpacademy.org)

Comment: please be more specific as to which line you want in native javascript and what you tried / failed at

Comment: I'm specifially looking for lines 5, 6, 9 and 15-19.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the lines where ever you select the element by **ID** with the corresponding ID

```
$('#cleared') --->  document.getElementById('cleared')
```

you can also use `querySelector` metod to access the element directly.

```
var cleared = document.querySelector('#cleared');
```

To `show` or `hide` a element you would need to set the `style.display` property

```
// To hide
cleared .style.display = "";
// To show
cleared .style.display = "block";
```

To get the element based on the attribute would be a bit of javascript..

```
$('[value='+transaction.type+']')
```

Where in you would need to iterate over each element and get the attribute of that element and then compare with the value.